Suitable candidates to ask for reference letters for PhD application?
I am going to graduate this semester and would like to apply for a PhD after a one-year research assistant position in the same lab I have been performing my two-year research projects.
I notice that quite many universities in Europe e.g. Germany and Switzerland, require 2 or sometimes 3 reference letters for the PhD application. However, I can only get one, which is from the PI of my current lab. There is also a mentor of mine (a PhD candidate), and a lab manager (did their PhD a long time ago, still participating in research), but I am not sure whether I can ask them for the letter since they are all in the same lab).
I am the second author of a journal article, and hopefully, a second paper will be under peer review by the end of my RA job, and I may be the co-first author or second author. But I can't really be sure about that since the project is only halfway done. (This is the main reason why I chose to stay in this lab)
Therefore, may I know who are common persons that I can ask for a reference letter?

You can ask anyone who knows your work. The fact that several are from the same lab does not disqualify them.
That said, some variety if probably better. Consider other professors in the department who know you.
The PI in the lab you work at now might have good suggestions.

Thanks. I understand that some variety is better, but most, if not all professors have only taught me for one semester (three months). Although I love asking 'good' questions (they claim) frequently, I don't think I know them, or they know me except in the lecture setting.
So, just to confirm, I can actually ask for others in the lab who know my projects and work ethic to write the second reference letter for me?

Yes, ask for the second letter from the person in your lab. Your cover letter might note that these people know you better than professors you only saw in class, even though you did well in those classes.
